# Access to API documentation on Docker

Tags: docker, api, swagger, fastapi

I have a fastapi and when I run it with uvicorn, I am able to open its api documentation through localhost/docs.

When I have this fastapi on docker, I am not able to see the API documentation.
Do I need to add an extra docker container for the API documentation?

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:   
    web:
        build: ui
        ports:
          - 80:80
        depends_on:
          - api

    api:
        build: app
        environment:
          - PORT=80
        ports:
          - 8020:80
```

and I run it with `docker-compose up --build`.

I tried localhost/docs and localhost/swagger/index.html and I wasn't able to see the API documentation on docker.

Here is my fastapi docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt /app/


RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8020"]
```

Comment: Could you access other paths? (e.g., `localhost:port/your/path`)

Comment: @l2D yes, I do.

Comment: I also have access to documentation with http://localhost:8020/docs when I run fastapi separately.

Comment: Have any logs on the Docker container when access to `/docs`?

Comment: @l2D web_1         | 172.23.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2022:16:02:13 +0000] "GET /ai-ocr/docs HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: I am able to see the html web at localhost/ai-ocr/. It's just a subdirectory.

Comment: Is your API working? (except `/docs`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245606/discussion-between-l2d-and-cfd).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is mismatching ports.

try

```
ports:
   - 8020:8020
```

then you can see docs at
http://0.0.0.0:8020/docs

Comment: I receive this error when I change the ports: "GET /ai-ocr/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: 304 is HTTP status error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304